# How to toggle part of the href in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently, I'm working on a voting system (Just like what we have in StackOverflow)

There are four seperate link types: up-vote on/off, down-vote on/off, which means that we allow user to vote and cancel their votes.
The href is like `/vote?type=up`, `/vote?type=off-up`

The problem is that I don't how to toggle the value of the type attribute(e.g. up/off-up) of the link
I found something like
`this.href = this.href.replace('up', 'off-up');`, but this is just one-direction.

Could you tell me how to make the **type** of the link toggleable? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use ternary operator

```
this.href = this.href.indexOf('off-up') != -1 ? this.href.replace('off-up', 'up') : this.href.replace('up', 'off-up');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't really toggle that in a simple way. Instead you can toggle toggle some custom data attribute:

```
var oLink = $(this);
oLink.data("off", !oLink.data("off"));
```

Then don't use the HREF directly but rather build it on the fly in the `.click()` event of the link, taking the value of `oLink.data("off")` into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
this.href = this.href.indexOf('off-up') > 0 ? this.href.replace('off-up', 'up') : this.href.replace('up', 'off-up');
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vjuqa/